# Convert SpeechRecognitionResultList to array?

Tags: javascript, webkitspeechrecognition

Is it possible to convert the SpeechRecognitionResultList to an array? It exposes an item getter and you can iterate over it with for of but i would like to convert to an array so I can use findIndex etc.

```js
    const speechRecognition = new window.webkitSpeechRecognition();
    speechRecognition.onresult = (event: any) => {
      // how to turn this into an array?
      event.results
    };
```

Comment: Try with [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: You should post, at least that particular piece of code, for people to understand better what you want and possibly help you better.

Comment: @Loolooii fair point added!